# assign date values to 2D array to fill a jtable

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

Starting date is today and End date should be today's date+3 years.As an example Strating date is 3.1.2014 .End date is 3.1.2017 .I want to fill the jtable using 2D array.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLR7F.jpg

```
    Date begindate = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(begindate);
    int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 3);
    Date enddate = cal.getTime();
    Date currentdate = begindate;
    while (true) {
        if (currentdate.getTime() >= enddate.getTime()) {
            break;
        } else {
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(begindate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, x++);
        Date newdate = c.getTime();
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        currentdate = newdate;
    }
```

Comment: in  above code how to assign values to 2D array?

Comment: I am not sure what is your question or where does your code snippet fit.  Would you please elaborate it?

Comment: yes. in the above code we can get the dates between today and 3years after today. i want to assign those dates to a table. http://i.stack.imgur.com/eLR7F.jpg
so i want to add those dates to the table using 2 dimentional array.how to create 2d array with this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calendar manipulations might work although it hurts my eyes somehow (another library like JodaTime would be better). About your question, I am not sure what you have formulated. Maybe you want to know how to map your dates to 2D-grid cells. Your variable x is a candidate. If you know how many cells are in a row (7?) then you can deduce from x-counter and current day of week in which cell the currentdate must be put in.

About your coding style:

I would avoid empty else-branches. I would also avoid constructions like `Calendar.getInstance()` and rather choose `new GregorianCalendar()` because you surely not want the buddhist calendar for example.

I would also prefer:

```
while (currentdate.getTime() < enddate.getTime()) {
```

By the way, here some untested thought experiments:

If you initialize x to zero indicating column = 0 and row = 0 then you have the relations:
x = col + 7 * row => `x / 7 = row` and `x % 7 = col`

After this you need to apply a correction for the position of weekdays relative to columns, maybe this way:

```
int m = (weekday - 1 - col) % 7; // weekday as Calendar-constant (Calendar.SUNDAY etc)
if (m < 0) {
  m += 7;
  row++;
}
col = (col + m) % 7;
```

All without guarantee, this is just a hint for your own experiments.

Comment: @user3155767 I have added an untested proposal, you can try it out.